# EventFiringWebDriver does not register WebElement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, frontend

I am testing frontend with Selenium using an EventFiringWebDriver to log WebElement manipulation.

findElement() calls work alright, but if I get get a WebElement through JavascriptExecutor, though, my WebDriverEventListener's listeners don't get called when I interact (click, sendKeys, etc.) with this element.
Is there a way to make the listener work with WebElements that come from the JavascriptExecutor's executeScript()?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately since you are interacting with the javascript itself and not the events on the webpage the events aren't considered fired as far as the eventlistener is concerned.
You'll have to manually manipulate the elements as though you were an enduser to get the listener to notice.